# How to accept secure websocket connections in HornetQ

Tags: ssl, websocket, hornetq

I'm trying to configure HornetQ to accept secure websocket connections (wss://) for STOMP communications. I'm using HornetQ 2.4.0.Final. I've been successful in configuring an unsecured connection like so:

```
<acceptor name="stomp-acceptor">
    <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
    <param key="protocols"  value="STOMP"/>
    <param key="host"  value="localhost"/>
    <param key="port"  value="61613"/>
</acceptor>
```

I tried adding `ssl-enabled`, `key-store-path`, and `key-store-password`, as well as the appropriate `trust-store-*` settings for the connector, as demonstrated in the `ssl-enabled` example included with HornetQ but have had no luck.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I'll explain, though my SSL terminology might be a bit weak.

The cert being presented was self-signed. As the browser did not initially trust the cert, the wss connection failed silently. As a workaround, I browsed to https://localhost:61613 and was presented by the browser with the typical security warning & prompt to proceed/confirm security exception. Once this was done, the wss:// connection was successfully established. This strategy worked in both Chrome and Firefox. (Too bad neither one tells you why the connection fails up front; would've saved a lot of time.)

This semi-related irc log helped; I wouldn't have thought to try an https:// connection otherwise: http://irclogs.dankulp.com/logs/irclogger_log/activemq?date=2013-06-28,Fri&text=on

Also helpful, in retrospect: [How to debug Safari silently failing to connect to a secure WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014055/how-to-debug-safari-silently-failing-to-connect-to-a-secure-websocket?rq=1)