# Webpack - Javascript/Es6

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, webpack, microsoft-edge

Just trying to run my app in Safari or Edge. http://ryanspice.com/test/

Unfortunately the console gives no errors, no compiling issues, and theres nothing signalling whats wrong. It seems to work perfectly in chrome and firefox.

Edit: From what I can tell the javascript is running

Here's my webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require('path');

require("babel-core/register");
require("babel-polyfill");

var env = process.argv.indexOf('--env') === -1 ? false : true;

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var source = {
    input:{
        js:'spice.js',
        html:'./src/index.html',
        path:'./src/',
    },

    output:{
        js:"spice.js",
        html:"../index.html"
    }
}

var webpack = require('webpack');

var webpackPlugins = [];

if (env===true)
{
    source.output.js = "spice.min.js";
    var webpackUglifyJsPlugin = webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin;
    var webpackHtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    webpackPlugins.push(new webpackUglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }));
    webpackPlugins.push(
        new webpackHtmlPlugin({
            filename: source.output.html, template:'./src/index.html'
        })
    );
}

module.exports = {

    entry: ["babel-polyfill", source.input.path + source.input.js],
    output: {
        path: __dirname+"/bld/vendor",
        filename: source.output.js
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
              test: /\.jsx?$/
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
          }
        ],
        sassLoader: {
          includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./css")]
        }
    },
    plugins: webpackPlugins
};
```

Here's my .babelrc

```js
{
    "presets": ["es2015","stage-0"]
}
```

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? There is not enough info here to work with.

Comment: It appears that the code is simply not running. I'm unsure how to debug it further, things seem normal in and around the dev tools.
EDIT: the compiled javascript

Comment: I'd set a breakpoint.

Comment: Within your webpack.config.js, you can print out info to your console with `process.stdout.write()`. So you can do something like this `process.stdout.write('value for source: ' + source);` to help narrow down if anything is suspect in your webpack config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug Safari silently failing to connect to a secure WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014055/how-to-debug-safari-silently-failing-to-connect-to-a-secure-websocket)