# Sudden SSL error in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, https, sslhandshakeexception

I really need help to fix this sudden SSL issue for my website on iPhone.

My client reports to me that all of their visitors from iPhone have not been able to open the site in the last 2 weeks.

**It used to work fine.**

Website url is: [Link](https://www.metta4life.org/)

It's hosted under a reseller account, and the SSL certificate is RapidSSL.

[image: Screenshot of SSL error]

I did a ssl test, and found out that there're warnings on Ios 9.

```
Safari 9 / iOS 9  R Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
Safari 9 / OS X 10.11  R    Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9  R  Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Is this what the problem was?
Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: restructured to make it clearer

Comment: Maybe [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4016461/1445366) will help?