# Websocket connection to google compute engine endpoint fails only in safari

Tags: javascript, spring, websocket, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I have a spring-boot websocket implementation where I have simply extended a `TextWebSocketHandler`. The websocket endpoint lays on a Google Compute Engine backend-service that has a http load balancer attached to it. When trying to establish a connection to this endpoint by simply doing

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://www.mydomain.com/compilews");
```

I get the following error only in Safari. It works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.mydomain.com/compilews' failed: No response code found: HTTP/1.1 101

What leads me to believe that the error has something to do with Google Compute Engine is that when I run the spring-boot websocket application locally I can connect to it without any problems from Safari. It just doesn't work when live on GCP. Reading about the setting up [http(s) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#websocket_proxy_support) tells me that no additional configuration is need for the websocket to work.

I'm still learning about all this and don't know how to debug this any further. I can't get anything of value out of the load balancer logs either. The following is logged when I try connecting from Safari which doesn't work.

```
statusDetails:  "websocket_closed"
```

Comment: Based on the HTTP/1.1 101 response and the load balancer logs statusDetails: "websocket_closed", there is not seem to be any issues on Google Compute Engine, but the way how Safari might be establishing the connection, is it possible that Safari is closing the connection immediately after being established? At this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015742), they suggested to trying something like 'http://ws://www.mydomain.com/compilews to see if you could get a better error message.

Comment: You might want also compare the traceback from Chrome and Firefox vs Safari. You can also try a tcpdump capture to further investigate why the connections are being closed.